JHipster project not logging exceptions on prod profile
I'm working on a Spring Boot project generated with JHipster v8.3.0. Everything works fine in the development profile, but when I switch to the production profile, the application does not log any errors. I've verified my configurations, but I'm still not able to see error logs.
I've set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod in my Heroku configuration.
I used heroku logs --tail to monitor the logs in real-time, but no error logs appear.
On the same env, with dev profile logs are correctly showsed.
Despite these settings, errors are not being logged when the application runs in production. Is there something I'm missing or any additional configurations I should check?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Did you find a solution for that yet?

At the moment i've added a log.error row on method handleAnyException on ExceptionTranslator class. This is obviously a workaround, I'm hoping for a suggestion for a permanent solution

I did the same as Nicola mentioned in his comment. Just with some extra checks to get less double log entries during development, and to only log "internal server errors".
But I guess there must be a better solution?
In ExceptionTranslator.java in handleAnyException method, add:
if (pdCause.getStatus() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() && !env.matchesProfiles("dev")) {
            // If profile is dev, then Logging Aspect will handle logging.
            // In all other profiles no error is logged :-( No idea why that should be a good decision.
            log.error("Internal Server error happened", ex);
}


You can add the prod profile in the logAfterThrowing method of the LoggingAspect class as follows:
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT, JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION))) {
           ...
        }

You will need to add the profile in LoggingAspectConfiguration class too.
It's a similar answer as Nicola's and RMM's but I think it's a little bit cleaner.
I prefer to add the profile because I'm adding a new one for stg environment.
